# Executing Python scripts in Vim such that Vim remembers previously run code

Tags: python

Supposing I have the following python script open in Vim:

```
a=1
b=2
c=a+b
```

I know that I can type

```
:! python3
```

in normal mode either for the whole script or by selecting the rows that I want to run in visual mode. But I can't run the first two lines and the third line *separately* without error as a and b won't be remembered by the interpreter.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031098/how-to-make-vim-remember-a-defined-variable-in-python) proposed solution but it doesn't solve the problem for me. Using :python3 (without the "!") results in "E471: Argument required". Someone at work implied from this that I need to compile Vim with Python3 support, but from researching this, it seems that I have it - see the output from the terminal command which has the "+" for python3/dyn

```
vim --version
```

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Apr 29 2022 00:00:00)
> Included patches: 1-4845 Modified by bugzilla@redhat.com Compiled by
> bugzilla@redhat.com Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+)
> or not (-):
> +acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
> +arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
> +autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
> +autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
> -autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
> -balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
> +balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
> -browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
> ++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
> +byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          +title
> +channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
> +cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
> -clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
> -clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
> +cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
> +cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
> +cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +virtualedit
> +comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
> +conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
> +cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
> +cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildignore
> +cursorbind        +lua/dyn           +scrollbind        +wildmenu
> +cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
> +dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
> +diff              +modify_fname      +sodium            -X11
> +digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
> -dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
> -ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
> +emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
> +eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
> +ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
> +extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
> -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static        system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
> user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"  2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
> user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
> defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"   fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim" Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2
> -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DSYS_VIMRC_FILE=/etc/vimrc -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1  Linking: gcc -L. -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lm -lselinux -lncurses -lsodium -lacl -lattr -lgpm -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lresolv -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc

I would be very grateful for any help. My OS is Fedora 35.

Comment: You could look into using two tmux panes (or GNU screen) - one running vim, and the other running python. The with a vim plugin [vim slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) you can 'send' whatever lines you want over to the python process.

Comment: when you say having vim "remember" the code that was run... do you mean precisely like a repl?

Comment: `:python3` requires a statement to run; see `:help python3`. You might also be interested in `:py3file` or something like `:execute 'python3' getline('.')`

Comment: @mattb Thanks, will give that a go.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Many thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for and clears up a lot of questions I had. Just one more, with :py3file the contents of :help py3file gives :[range]py3f[ile] {file} but when I enter, say :1,2 py3file myscript.py the whole script is executed, not just lines 1 and 2 (same if I try selecting those lines in visual mode first) - have I misunderstood or misused [range]?

Comment: @Damask_Rose frankly I’m mot sure what `[range]` does for any except `:pydo` :( it’s under-documented.

Comment: I recommend using https://github.com/bfredl/nvim-ipy , the vim counterpart is  https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython

Comment: I use [Vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) for this sort of thing. Googling for `vim slime` or `vim repl` will turn up a bunch of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you want vim to execute the code internally, `:python3` requires a statement to run; see `:help python3`. You might also be interested in `:py3file` or something like `:execute 'python3' getline('.')`. (Unfortunately the `[range]` specifier for these commands is undocumented.)

---

On the other hand, you may want a different workflow (say, using a tmux pane and `:Twrite` from [tbone](https://github.com/tpope/vim-tbone)) to send code to an actual python instance.